# Unknown function 'org.neo4j.examples.join' on neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to creating user defined procedure.

i got the sample project from this github repository https://github.com/neo4j-examples/neo4j-procedure-template. i created the jar file and moved to /var/lib/neo4j/plugins
i am getting the unknown function error

If anyone knows about it help me please
also i restarted my neo4j also

`neo4j> MATCH (p: Person) WHERE p.age = 36  RETURN org.neo4j.examples.join(collect(p.names));
Unknown function 'org.neo4j.examples.join' (line 1, column 44 (offset: 43))
"MATCH (p: Person) WHERE p.age = 36  RETURN org.neo4j.examples.join(collect(p.names));"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the comment on the java method for this function, you will see into the description annotation, that to call it you should do : `example.join(...)` and  NOT `org.neo4j.examples.join`.

This function is under the java package `example`, and the name of the function is `join`, so it gives you `example.join`

You can define manually what is the way to call a function by adding a `name` attribut into the UserFunction annotation. Like this :

```
@UserFunction( "test.nodeList" )
public List<Object> nodeList()
{
    Result result = db.execute( "MATCH (n) RETURN n LIMIT 1" );
    Object node = result.next().get( "n" );
    return Collections.singletonList( node );
}
```

And call it in cypher like this :

```
RETURN test.toSet(['a', 'b'])
```

Comment: I tried with `MATCH (p: Person) WHERE p.age = 36  RETURN examples.join(collect(p.names));` still same error only

Comment: there is no `S` at example ! Just `example.join`

Comment: My bad. Sorry i didn't see that. Thanks for the answer